# Invalid use of group function 250 search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, server-error

I have a table linked to other  table  when i dispay in in php it does not show any error  but once I type anyword in search text box and serach an error come ou  with     Invalid use of group function this  is my sql

```
SELECT serFacture.Id,
serFacture.InvId,
serFacture.`date`,
serFacture.Customer,
serFacture.Supplier,
 serFacture.DeliveryDate,
 serFacture.editor,
 serFacture.paydate,
 serFacture.status,
 serFacture.huandanhao,
 SUM(`Order`.jianshu) AS carton,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `Order`.yisong = 'Daole' THEN `Order`.jine ELSE 0 END) As TotalAmount,
 SUM(`Order`.jine) AS amount,
 serFacture.total,
 serFacture.deposit,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `Order`.yisong = 'Daole' THEN `Order`.jine ELSE 0 END) - serFacture.deposit AS ToBePaid
FROM serFacture
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Order` ON serFacture.InvId = `Order`.OrdId
GROUP BY serFacture.Id, serFacture.InvId, serFacture.`date`, serFacture.Customer, serFacture.Supplier, serFacture.DeliveryDate,   serFacture.editor
```

and this is  a capture of the error 
[image: error ;essage]

Please help

Comment: What happens when you put that query into a simple SQL client like phpmyadmin?

Comment: the code  above  works  properly , even in list page  here is no error  , the  error  comes  when i search for anyword   with the search panel

Comment: Show your full query with the WHERE clause